# Auth guard is not waiting for local storage

Tags: angular, angular6

I have Auth guard which is based on the local storage value if it is present or not. But what happened canActivate() function return null value before getting value from local storage. What can i do to achieve this mechanism?

My code

```
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    this.check = this.usr.getUserLoggedIn().subscribe((data) => {
      // this.check = data;
      console.log(data);
    });
    // console.log('check', this.check);
    if (this.check === true) {
      return true;
    } else {
      // alert('else');
      this.router.navigate(['/authentication/login']);
      return false;
    }
}
```

Service Function Code :

```
getUserLoggedIn() {
    return this.localStorage.getItem('isUserLoggedIn');
    // return this.isUserLoggedIn;
  }
```

Comment: Add your logic inside the setTimeout method, so that there would be sometime to get the localstorage value. No need to set any delay value, it can be 0 as well.

Comment: Because your canActivate method doesn't actually return an observable of Boolean

Comment: @jonrsharpe How can i pass this local storage value which is set to true to the canActivate Function because i have to pass this value to canActivate to further routing is there is any way to achive this mechanism?

Comment: You don't subscribe in the method, you return an observable and let the framework subscribe. Change the signature to only include `Observable<boolean>` as a valid return and see what warnings you get.